# Coercing to Unicode with file upload in Django

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am playing around with file uploads in Django however I am getting this error:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/TrinityTaaS/parser/views.py" in handle_uploaded_file
  35.     f = open(log_file, "r")

Exception Type: TypeError at /parser/events/
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, WSGIRequest found
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue.

views.py

```
def handle_uploaded_file(log_file):
    print "HI"
    json_beacons = []
    f = open(log_file, "r")
    # log regex for events
    beacon1 = re.compile(r'.*\[DataCapture\]\s+(?P<beacon_var>\[(.*)\])')
    beacon2 = re.compile(r'.*\[DataCapture\]\s+Event:\s+\{.*\}(?P<beacon_var>\{.*\})')
    for chunk in f.chunk():
        log_entry = re.search(beacon1, chunk)
        if log_entry:
            beacon_json = log_entry.group("beacon_var")
            json_beacons.append(beacon_json[1:-1])
    return json_beacons

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            json_beacons = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error infers that `log_file` is a response object, my guess is that you're actually referencing `handle_uploaded_file` in your url configuration rather than `upload_file`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the likely incorrect url config SmileyChris mentioned, `open` expects a string containing a path to a file, while `request.FILES` contains objects representing the file as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files

You don't need to `open` the uploaded file, just use its `read` or `chunks` methods to get the uploaded content.